# GFCI From previous 120v double oven vs. a different GFCI for new 240v double oven

Tags: gfci

do you need a new/different GFCI receptacle when you upgrade/change your 120v double oven to a 240v double oven?

Comment: You will need a different breaker but not a GFCI.

Comment: Are you changing a gas oven for an electric oven?

Answer (score 1):

Electric ovens take an **enormous** amount of power and that cannot possibly be delivered through common outlets.

Be prepared to hire an electrician to run a new set of heavy duty cables from your breaker panel to the oven location.

If your oven is in a standard location, the correct cables might already be present, just unused.   Also, sometimes when a conversion to gas is done, the old heavy cabling is converted for use with the normal socket.  Perhaps the GFCI you now see actually has the correct, heavy cabling behind it.

Your oven cannot use  a GFCI receptacle. However, with certain older wiring configurations, which lack a safety ground, you would be wise to fit a GFCI circuit breaker to avoid a very dangerous situation where a routine wire failure could electrify the chassis of the oven.